# Not able to run web API on https using docker-compose

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

My problem is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510618/docker-compose-up-build-on-wsl2-ubuntu-gives-me-unable-to-start-kestrel). But there's no solution posted.

Things work ok if I let visual studio run it through the dockerfile, but trying to run it using docker compose manually doesn't work (error is the same as the linked question).

For additional details, here's the service in docker-compose.yml

```yaml
api-service:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
restart: always
ports:
  - 5000:80
  - 5001:443
volumes:
  - $APPDATA\microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
  - $APPDATA\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
  - $USERPROFILE\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
environment:
  MongoDB__Host: mongo
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
  ASPNETCORE_URLS: https://+:443;http://+:80
  NUGET_PACKAGES: /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
  NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES: /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
depends_on:
  - mongo
```

As you can see I have mounted the volumes for the pfx certificate and usersecrets. But I still can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? Do you get errors?

Comment: Error is the same as the linked question. (edited my question to state this)

Comment: I have a feeling `$APPDATA` and `$USERPROFILE` are not getting replaced correctly.

Comment: The mounts are resolved to correct path, I have checked the paths by inspecting the container on docker desktop.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on setting up ssl certificate for kestrel ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0#replace-the-default-certificate-from-configuration)? It's failing to find the certificate in the default location. You can follow the instructions above and provide a path to the certificate in the appsettings. Another useful article is the one on generating a ssl certificate for linux. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/#linux-mac

Comment: @allan - I've used `dotnet dev-certs https` for creating a self-signed certificate. And I've provided the correct certificate path and password through `user-secrets`

Comment: Could you include the contents of the appsettings file showing the variables and paths to the certificate?